# pandas shift with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have a dataframe

```
rr = pd.DataFrame([['A', pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01'), 12],
                   ['A', pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01'), 6],
                   ['A', pd.to_datetime('2010-03-01'), 3]], columns = ['id','date', 'variable'])
```

sucht that  rr :

```
    id  date        variable
0   A   2010-01-01  12
1   A   2010-01-01  6
2   A   2010-03-01  3
```

I would like to have:

```
    id  date    date_lead       variable
0   A   2010-01-01  2010-02-01  1
1   A   2010-02-01  2010-03-01  12
2   A   2010-02-01  2010-03-01  6
3   A   2010-03-01  NaT         3
```

A normal shift operation will not suffice. How do I achieve this

Comment: What is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to add 1 day to column `rr['date']` then this should work:

```
rr['date_lead']=rr['date']+pd.DateOffset(days=1)
```